# Is there a fast technique to tell that the poles of $\frac{1}{\sin z}$ are simple?

Tags: complex-analysis

Is there a systematic way to determine the order of a pole of a function? For instance, I want to calculate the residues of $\frac{1}{\sin z}$, for the poles at $k\pi$.

If the poles are simple, and apparently they are, it's easy to see the residues to be $(-1)^k$. However, how can one tell the poles are simple?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

1. A pole of $f$ is a zero of $1/f$ and vice verse.
2. What can you say about $\sin z/z$ as $z\to0$?

Answer (score 2):

You are asking if the zeros of $\sin z$ are simple. It suffices to check that at each zero $z_0$, the derivative $\cos z_0 \neq 0$, which is easy to check. (Reason: look at the Taylor expansion around $z_0$. If it is not a simple zero, the derivative would be 0 at $z_0$)

Comment: So in general, is the order of the pole the same as the order of the zero of the denominator?

Comment: Yes, by definition of order of pole/zero.

Comment: @Cye I am sure you know that, you should just think it over...

Comment: Guess I had a bad misunderstanding! Thanks both.

Comment: To be bit picky: In general it's not the order of the zero of the denominator but the order of the zero of the reciprocal $1/f$.